# is there a way to specify what should be in a list when passed as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-typing

I am learning python. I have a function:

```
def saveQuotesAndData(self,filename:str, items:list):
```

but I want my VS Code intellisense to know what items[i] will be, so i can write the function with auto complete, and not manually type properties of items[i].

for example if I want to auto complete below:

items[i].QuoteTime

maybe something like this would be perfect:

```
def saveQuotesAndData(self,filename:str, items:list<Quote>):
```

where Quote would be the expected class contained in the list.

something as simple as this is very slow in python so far for me because theres lots of manual typing and flicking back to class definitions. any suggestions here?

Comment: You need to learn about [generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `def saveQuotesAndData(self,filename:str, items:list[Quote])`

Answer (score 1):

From the [type hints cheat sheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#useful-built-in-types):

```py
# For collections on Python 3.9+, the type of the collection item is in brackets
x: list[int] = [1]
x: set[int] = {6, 7}

# For mappings, we need the types of both keys and values
x: dict[str, float] = {"field": 2.0}  # Python 3.9+

# For tuples of fixed size, we specify the types of all the elements
x: tuple[int, str, float] = (3, "yes", 7.5)  # Python 3.9+

# For tuples of variable size, we use one type and ellipsis
x: tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3)  # Python 3.9+
```

So in your example, you would define the function as:

```py
def saveQuotesAndData(self, filename: str, items: list[Quote]):
    ...
```